# Is there a way to view the underlying Git commit that LibGit2Sharp issues?

Tags: libgit2sharp

I'm working with LibGit2Sharp, but the performance is so poor as to be worthless. When I execute what I THINK is the equivalent Git command against the repo, it performs just fine...is there any way to see what LibGit2Sharp is doing under the covers to see why it's performing so badly?

Comment: No -- there is no underlying git command.  Can you post some code and a reproduction case?

Comment: I did that first, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598990/how-can-i-get-the-last-commit-for-a-folder-using-libgit2sharp